# QT Creator Keypad

Tags: qt, widget, keypad

So I have an app that I am developing in qt and I have a fair amount of C/C++ experience but this is my first foray into GUI design so with that being said I have my app functioning as I want it to function but I am repeating alot of code for my keypad I am copy and pasting it into each UI file for the corrosponding dialog windows and then copy all the slots for it

```
void Login_Dialog::on_KP1_clicked()

QKeyEvent key(QKeyEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_1, Qt::NoModifier, "1", false, 0 );
    QApplication::sendEvent(this->focusWidget(), &key);
```

wondering how I can create a separate UI/cpp/h files with the corrosponding slots  and then embed it in the dialogs where I want to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can directly used Qt Virtual Keyboard 1.1 to get keypad layout.

if you want costume layout for your keypad. you need to create QWidgets of your costume layouts of keypad. Bellow link provided you guidance to create costume qwidget in qt:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Isn't qtkeyboard part of the enterprise package?

Comment: Qt Virtual keyboard is available in enterprise package in version Qt 5.3.1. Which qt version you are using?

Comment: I am using the free version

Comment: Create custom widget keyboard.

Comment: That's what is was trying to do and I solves it myself thanks for the input